# Why is the navbar-brand link clickable only when the navbar is collapsed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap on a project and I have the following HTML (currently visible [here](http://skillshare.im/)):

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation'>
  <div class='navbar-header'>
    <button class='navbar-toggle' data-target='#header-navbar' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
      <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class='icon-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar'></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://ea-skillshare.herokuapp.com/">Sharing Is Caring</a>
  </div>
  ...
</nav>
```

If you try to click on the link with the text "Sharing Is Caring," nothing will happen. However, it is possible to select the link and navigate to the URL it points at if you use the tab key to highlight it and then press enter:

[image]

The link also works when the menu is collapsed, as below:

[image]

How can I make the link work all the time?

Comment: The solution contained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829623/collapse-button-in-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-not-clickable works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tells me you are trying to use Bootstrap 3 while your application on Heroku seems to be including Bootstrap 2.3.2.  If you're able to update the css/js files that are being loaded on the site to BS 3 you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I first used the [Twitter Bootstrap Rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) (which uses Bootstrap 2) before removing it and installing the [Bootstrap Rails gem](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) (which uses Bootstrap 3). I think some of the old compiled assets were hanging around. When I deleted them and recompiled, the problem disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: I've had a lot of issues myself using the first gem you mentioned with bootstrap 3, but it is possible.

Answer (score 8):

The Solution to your problem is very simple. The problem is because the "navbar-header" class has a property :float" with a value "left".
There are at least two ways to solve this problem that i know.
1).Add a "navbar-right" class to the next div immediately after the navbar-header. i.e

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
    <button class='navbar-toggle' data-target='#header-navbar' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://ea-skillshare.herokuapp.com/">Sharing Is Caring</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" collapse="!isCollapsed">
    ...
</div>
```

2). Add the float property with a value "right" to the next div yourself. be careful anyway because your collapsed menu floats to the right with the second solution.

Comment: This solution solves the problem raised by this post.  However, it moves the subsequent div (the navigation links) to the right.  Because it's a responsive design, moving them all the way to the right does not look good.  Can you make this work without altering the look of the navbar?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the above solution doesn't work, I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by removing an added `position: relative` class from my navbar-header element.

Background: I was using bootstrap 3.2.0 and my navbar-brand link would only work when the navbar was collapsed. I had given the navbar menu `position: absolute` so I could align it along the edge and bottom of a `.container` with `position:relative`. However, I had also added the `position: relative` to my navbar-header element, which was unnecessary and broke my link.

Answer (score 0):

I have found better solution for this. Just remove the `class="navbar-brand"` from the `<a>` tag and add `<div>` before it:

```
<div class="navbar-brand"><a href="http://ea-skillshare.herokuapp.com/">Sharing Is Caring</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, the solution to this for me was different. The `<a class="navbar-brand"...>...</a>` was placed outside the `<nav class='navbar....>...</nav>`. Moving it in (and at the top) helped resolve the issue.