# Collapse button in Twitter bootstrap navbar not clickable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When my navbar collapses the links and dropdown hide correctly and the button to display them shows but is not clickable.
If I replace my navbar with the code on the bootstrap page then the bootstrap example bar and collapse button performs correctly, so it is a problem with my HTML somewhere..

My code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class= "navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-link nav brand">
        <a href="/">MarcB</a>
    </div>   
  </div>   
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %> </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <% if current_user %>
      <li> <%= link_to "Sign Out", logout_path %> </li>
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right signed-in"> Signed in as:  <%= current_user.name %> </p>
    <% else %>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Log in <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Log in with Facebook', "/auth/facebook" %></li>  
            <li><%= link_to 'Log in with LinkedIn', "/auth/linkedin" %></li>  
            <li><%= link_to 'Log in with GitHub', "/auth/github" %></li>  
            <li><%= link_to 'Log in with Google+', "/auth/gplus" %></li>  
          </ul>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the generated HTML from rails is (not signed in)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class= "navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-link nav brand">
        <a href="/">MarcB</a>
    </div>   
  </div>   
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/posts">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Log in <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/auth/facebook">Log in with Facebook</a></li>  
            <li><a href="/auth/linkedin">Log in with LinkedIn</a></li>  
            <li><a href="/auth/github">Log in with GitHub</a></li>  
            <li><a href="/auth/gplus">Log in with Google+</a></li>  
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried commenting out the second ul with the dropdown - produces the same unclickable button.

Comment: Try putting high `z-index` on button e.g. `button {position: relative; z-index: 100000; }`.

Comment: That did it - so simple, thanks. Do you want to post that as an answer and not a comment?

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put high `z-index` on button e.g.

```
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```